# How to make the feature 'Replace Task Manager' of Process Explorer?

Tags: windows, winapi, win32-process, sysinternals, process-explorer

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) has a nice feature *Replace Task Manager*

[image]

I just wondered how Mark Russinovich implements this.
What trick is used for implementing this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use ProcMon to find out how it's done...

To save you the bother, ProcExp is defined as the debugger of taskmgr.exe in [`Image File Execution Options`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) on the registry. This means ProcExp is launched before taskmgr starts to run, no matter how taskmgr was launched. Then, ProcExp can easily close task manager and show itself.